# Can't add class while Hover function is in effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

### What I'm Trying To Do

I have a list (`ul#portfoliolist`) where each item is a different navigation item.

When the user hovers over any item, the opacity changes from `0.65` to `1`, and the right padding changes from `0` to `10px`. These are reversed when the user moves the mouse away:

```
$('ul#portfoliolist>li:not(.active)').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({paddingRight:'10px',opacity:1},100);
},function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({paddingRight:0,opacity:0.65},300);
})
```

If a user clicks on the list item, it removes the class `active` from any other list items and adds the class `active` to the clicked element:

```
$('ul#portfoliolist>li').click(function(){
    $('ul#portfoliolist>li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    //var item = $(this).attr('data-portfolio');
    //$('div.portfolio').css({backgroundImage:'url(img/portfolio_'+item+'.png)'})
})
```

### The issue I'm having

While these two functions work perfectly well alone, when combining them I'm unable to do both - only the hover effect is successful.

When I hover over, the desired animation works, but when I move the cursor away the secondary hover function occurs and that overrides the `.active` css.

How can I make the `click` function take priority over the `mouseout` part of the `hover` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that just writing this out on StackOverflow made it clear enough that I could find a solution myself:

```
$('ul#portfoliolist>li:not(.active)').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({paddingRight:'10px',opacity:1},100);
},function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).stop().animate({paddingRight:0},300);
    } else {
        $(this).stop().animate({paddingRight:0,opacity:0.65},300);
    }
})
```

As the `.active` class is added between the `mouseover` and `mouseout` part of the `hover` function, I added an `if` statement to the `mouseout` function to see if, during the time in which the cursor has entered the element, the class `.active` has been added.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul#portfoliolist>li:not(.active)').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({paddingRight:'10px',opacity:1},100);
},function(){
    if($this).hasClass('active'){
        return;
    }
    $(this).stop().animate({paddingRight:0,opacity:0.65},300);
})
```